# Regex for Home/House Address validation in EXTJS

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I tried below regex  expressions for house address validation
please give your suggestions on it.

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9#][-:,#. /A-Za-z0-9][a-zA-z]$
^\d*[a-zA-Z#, .:-]+[a-zA-z0-9, #.:]*

 Example Address:
 #43,
 JohnStreet,
 Sidney,
 AUS
```

Conditions:

```
1.Door number must be 1-4 digits(ex: 1, 12, 56, 568, 5698, #12, #123, #1235)
 It should notbe like 123456, 132adfs
2.It should be like 
 809,
 Bangloore,
 Karnataka,
 India
3.We should't allow only numerics in complete address
```

Comment: What is wrong with your regex? The `A-z` is a typo, right? Must be `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: it is allowing me to enter more than 4 digits in door number

Comment: More than 4? Your pattern only matches 3 character strings (lines).

Comment: I tried with second regex also please look into second regex

Comment: I do not get it: you want to use the same regex for all the lines?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you need. But here is a clue: [`^(?!#\d{5})\d*[a-zA-Z#, .:-]+[a-zA-Z0-9, #.:]*`](https://regex101.com/r/fO9sQ0/1).

Answer (score 0):

`^#?\d+,\r?\n[a-zA-Z#, .:-]+,\r?\n[a-zA-Z#, .:-]+,\r?\n[a-zA-Z#, .:-]+$`

- `^` start of string
- `#?` hash (aka pound) character. the question mark makes it optional.
- `(?:[1-9]\d{0,3})` a single character between 1 and 9. Then between 0 and 3 digits between 0 and 9.

The above matches `#1` `#70` `999` `9018` but not `09` `88880` `-9981`.

---

- `,\r?\n` the end of the line: a comma, an optional "carriage return" character (you sometimes see it when reading a file, server-side), then a "newline" character
- `[a-zA-Z#, .:-]+` any of the legal characters in the character set (I gather you understand that part).
- `,\r?\n` end of the line
- `[a-zA-Z#, .:-]+` legal characters
- `,\r?\n` end of the line
- `[a-zA-Z#, .:-]+` legal characters

---

- `$` end of the string